# how to convert 0 to 5 V signal into 4 to 20mA current transmitter

Tags: constant-current

i want to make a voltage to current converter which is also known as current transmitter. i want to  convert 0 to 5v into a 4 to 20mA current loop which can be received by a powered load. i want to make the circuit using op-amp. please someone help me by suggesting some tested circuit.
thanks in advance

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f70Pmx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: and :
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82129/5vdc-to-4-20ma-converter

Comment: and: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/307456/4-20ma-output-from-arduino/307460

Comment: maybe http://tinyurl.com/ydebnmcx